# Doctrine 2 Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have the Fields the Type DATETIME and Other DATE but when i INSERT NULL I have This Error :
  on  controller i set that :`$data ['dateCreation']        = $tab['dateCrea'];`

$tab['dateCrea'] somtimes NULL other Times 123614 or 21/12/2014 21:05:00 or others time

in Entity I do That

```
public function setModificationdate($modificationdate)
    {
        $this->modificationdate = new \DateTime($modificationdate);

        return $this;
    }
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object  in
>   C:\wamp\www\imprimvert\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php
>   on line 53

How can i resolve that

Comment: Please provide the mapping information for this entity :)

Answer (score 0):

As your property is of type `date` (or `datetime`), the first argument of your `setModificationDate` should be a `\DateTime`, e.g:

```
public function setModificationdate(\DateTime $modificationdate = null)
{
    $this->modificationdate = $modificationdate;

    return $this;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
$object->setModificationDate(new \DateTime());
```

Comment: ,so sometime i get $poste contains NULL and sometimes i get 12/12/2015

Comment: What do you expect ? Do you want that `modificationDate` stay up-to-date by setting it on each updater of your object? Or do you just want call it when you want

Comment: So i have Sometime in Object this date contains NULL and other in my boucle i found this date contains date such as 12/12/15 or other time i need it's work for all the cas

Comment: What's the difference between your first comment and the second, you just repeating yourself, answer chalasr question...